# history.push() not working - updatng the url but not diverting

Tags: reactjs

I have seen multiple answers on this question, still couldn't figure out

I'm using

```
`"  "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",`
```

// app.js

```
import history from "./history";
import { Router } from 'react-router';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/first/" component={MN} />                
          <Route path="/test/" component={Test} />
        </div>     
      </Router>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
};
```

// history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

//calling in component

```
import history from "./history";
....

history.push('mn/testing')
```

//mn.js

```
import history from "../history";
const Mn = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       <Router history={history}>
        <Route exact path="*/testing" component={DashBoard} />
        
        />
      </Router>
     
    </div>
  );
```

Edit: I have nested routes, is that creating an error?

Comment: You can try with `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: @Asifvora this is not working

Comment: Had you install `react-router-dom` and configure?

Comment: @Asifvora yes I have. It's changing the url but not loading the page

Comment: @Asifvora have updated my ques. please check

Comment: You need to change your `app.js` file

Comment: @Asifvora please specify, what change needs to be done

Comment: `import { Router } from 'react-router';` to `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `useHistory()` hook provided by react-router

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is throwing the error : 
react-dom.development.js:336 Uncaught TypeError: func.apply is not a function